# How to make sure cmake refers to specific folder instead of system folders

Tags: cmake

How to make sure cmake refers to specific folder for header files and library ?

Suppose I have a upstream component A installed in the below location instead of system folder like `/usr/local` :

`./configure --prefix=/home/user/project/INSTALLPATH/`

The `INSTALLPATH` Directory has below subdirectories like below: `bin`, `etc`, `include`, `lib`, `libexec`, `share`, `var`. Also, there is pkg-config file: `lib/pkgconfig`

Another B component wants refers to header and library of component A installed above in the specific `INSTALLPATH` location instead of system location. I set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to make sure it uses the component A headers and libraries as shown below

```
> echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/home/user/project/INSTALLPATH/lib/pkgconfig/:/home/user/project/INSTALLPATH/lib/pkgconfig/
```

I only see the headers being refered but I get linking errors because it cannot take find the library in `/home/user/project/INSTALLPATH/lib/`. How to make sure cmake refers  to specific folder instead of system folders?

Comment: What does this have to with configure/automake? "How to make sure cmake refers to specific folder for header files and library"? -- elaborate: which headers/libraries?

Comment: Got dbus-1.11.0.tar.gz from http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus/

Comment: Please amend + format your question properly. It's unsolvable as it currently is.

Comment: i see what the question has to do with `configure` (at least it is used to install *component A*); howerver, i totally fail to see how this is related to `cmake`: what is the cmake-code that is failing?